# Two branch both modified, how to merge them correctly?

Tags: git

I have a branch `DEV`, I created a branch `ESLINT` from it.

The branch `ESLINT` is supposed to hold a huge coding-style modification (I had no coding style before, now I have one) so **all the file** are beeing modified on it (indentation, unusedd-var, illegal whitespaces, ...).

During the work on this `ESLINT` branch, I had to add features in existing files & new file to the branch `DEV` (new feature, not a super clean workflow for now so I develop new features directly on `DEV`).

I'd like to kow how can I update `ESLINT` with the modification I done in `DEV` (new files & new file content in existing files)

I though of doing `git checkout ESLINT` then `git merge DEV` but I'm afraid of the mess it may create.

Comment: Are you familiar with *merge confilcts* and *resolving* them?

Comment: Even if you combine some trouble you can (almost?) always revert to current state using `reflog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a lot of conflicts, prepare youself to resolve them.

Common practice is to rebase feature branch on current develop before merging. This will produce conflicts, but if develop does not change during this time - the following merge back into develop will be simple.

So do `git checkout -b ESLINT-rebased && git rebase DEV` (first one is to save previous state in case you get completely lost) while being on `ESLINT`, then read what it says.
It will list files with conflicts and mark these inside with `<<<<<` (you can grep for that) - you can read about resolving for example [here](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at `git rebase`. You'd be wise to try it on a separate branch, because it can similarly get confusing, especially if you're not completely familiar with git, but something like:

```
git checkout ESLINT
git checkout -b ESLINT-rebase-test
git rebase DEV
```

What this should do is effectively to park your changes on ESLINT, since it last diverged from DEV, then re-apply them one commit at a time on top of what was in DEV. You can still get conflicts, which you resolve in the same way as merge conflicts, and I'd advise reading a more full tutorial on rebase, before you try this, to get a proper understanding of how to deal with these conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid conflicts. If you want to take this step by step, you can cherry-pick commits one by one, from one branch to the other and fix conflicts for each one until you have finished with both branches.